# Cannot download image from specific URL

Tags: swift

I have a image URL here:
[https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/あRP27988_1012.jpg](https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/%E3%81%82RP27988_1012.jpg)

then I encoded it to: 
https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/%E3%81%82RP27988_1012.jpg

I've tried Kingfisher, SDWebImage and also URLSession to download it but all failed. I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/%E3%81%82RP27988_1012.jpg")!) {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
        print(data) // 76606 bytes
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!) // nil 
        }
    }.resume()
```

Anyone can give me some advices ? Thank you

Comment: I've tried your code, and it's not a valid image. HTTP Response says `"Content-Type" = ("image/jpeg");`, but data starts with `524946463`. That's not a JPEG which "JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9". Doesn't seems valid to me.

Comment: @Larme so what should I do, any solution here ?

Comment: I've tried download image from the url, it cannot be open. So confused, the url still show us an image but this image is not valid ??

Comment: I can't see it in Safari, but in Chrome. I guess it's a new "format", websomething. Ask the back-end to have a "normal version". You can't do anything about that.

Comment: "52494646" (the first bytes of your images), correspond to "RIFF" in ASCII. And there is a little after "57454250" which is "WEBP" in ASCII. Seems to be WEBP format to me (https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container) So you need to be able to read WebP format. Not that easy. There might be third party lib that exist

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use `KingfisherWebp` library and it's worked

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some debug

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/%E3%81%82RP27988_1012.jpg")!) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let response = response else {
        print("No response")
        return
    }
    print("Response:\n\(response)")

    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }

    print("data.count: \(data.count)")

    //Is image valid/interpreted as such?
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    print(image ?? "no image")

    //Get first 100 bytes because all of it isn't necessary
    let subData = Data(data.prefix(100))
    //Convert it into "hex string"
    let hexString = subData.reduce("", { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) })
    print("HexString: \(hexString)")

}.resume()
```

This prints

```
Response:
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000269a460> { URL: https://spi-ra.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/%E3%81%82RP27988_1012.jpg } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" =     (
        bytes
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        76606
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "image/jpeg"
    );
    ...
} }
data.count: 76606
no image
HexString: 52494646362b010057454250565038202a2b0100b002049d012a1c031c023e6d3093472422a1a529571b68a00d8945bd76d35a3d9576f28c75a36dd6cdfe8bc8d375a3dfe23abbba7231d4dedcd9b5f7da446bf2ef8ff1d0ff3771ff33ff9bcd77ddfbe6
```

JPEG images should start with "FFD8", not "5249".

Debug add-on: Opening link with *Safari.app* doesn't show an image, but opening it with *Chrome.app* works.

A few search after looking at [the documentation of WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container), because I remember WebP was a "Google Format" (explaining why its works on Chrome, but not Safari).

```
let riffData = "RIFF".data(using: .ascii)
let webpData = "WEBP".data(using: .ascii)
print("riffData: \(riffData?.reduce("", { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }))")
print("webpData: \(webpData?.reduce("", { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }))")
```

Gives:

```
riffData: Optional("52494646")
webpData: Optional("57454250")
```

We see the same start, and find webpData later (check the doc/headers lengths).

So it's a WebP image, which isn't translated natively by iOS. You have to use a third party lib or code you own to show that image.

According to your comments, there is a KingfisherWebp which does it.